# When should I use public, private, or [SerializeField]? Unity C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

When should I use public, private, or [SerializeField]? which is the most practical?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

First, you need to make sure you understand the difference between public and private variables. [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/access-modifiers)'s the official documentation for different access modifiers. I strongly recommend you read through it, but a simple version would be that public variables can be referenced by other classes, while private variables cannot.
Imagine if you have a `Player` class with a `Health` field. Let's assume that by your design, you want a `GameManager` class to check the `Player`'s health to determine if the player is alive. If the `Health` field is public, this is possible by referencing `Player.Health`
If the `Health` field is private, it can only be accessed inside the `Player` class.

In the context of Unity, public fields are displayed in the inspector, so if you attach the `Player` component to a `GameObject`, the `Health` field will be visible and you will be able to edit it in the Inspector. If the field is private, you will not see it in the Inspector.

There are however cases where you want to have a private field visible in the Inspector or a public field hidden in the inspector. For these purposes we have `[SerializeField]` and `[HideInInspector]`. As the names suggest, `[SerializeField]` can be added before a private field to make it visible in the inspector and `[HideInInspector]` can be added before a public field to hide it in the inspector.

When declaring a new variable, keep it private by default, unless you expect to refrence it from another class. Then, after your code is written, add `[SerializeField]` and `[HideInInspector]` if necessary to achieve the desired appearance of  the component in the Inspector.

Comment: Some examples would be helpful to clarify when to use [SerializeField] private for example. The answer explains very good what it does but not when to use it.

Comment: Say you have:
private int number = 1;

That wont show within unity, but say you want to change that variable in unity, adding

[serialized]
private int number = 1;

now you can edit in unity

Answer (score 0):

Doing this on phone so hopefully I get this about right.
**public** gives access to any and all other components to access the variable

**private** restricts access to the script itself to access it but doesn't mean you can't make it accessible.

```
[SerializeField] private int hiddenNumber = 101;
public int HiddenNumber
{
    get
    {
        return hiddenNumber;
    }
}
```

This makes the variable accessible from other components but they won't be able to set the variable to anything.

Edit: Forgot to add you can also just do

```
public int hiddenNumber {get; private set;}
public int HiddenNumber {get; private set;} = 102;
```

Answer (score 0):

- public ==> **read and write**
- [SerializeField] private ==> **read only**